# Error when displaying fetched data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, single-page-application

I'm building an SPA where a Vue component is responsible for fetching an item and displaying the relevant information. I get an item when the Vue component is created and load it up into the appropriate object in data like so:

```
created(){
    axios.get('/projects/' + this.$route.params.slug)
        .then(response => this.project = response.data);
},
```

Where

```
data() {
    return {
        project: {}
    }
},
```

I'm then trying to display the item's title:

```
<h1 v-text="project.item.title"></h1>
```

The datum sent from the server looks like so:

```
return Response::json([
    'item' => $project,
], 200);
```

I'm utilizing Laravel in the backend, so a collection($project) is returned:

```
Project {#190 ▼
  #label: array:1 [▶]
  #fillable: array:5 [▶]
  #connection: "mysql"
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:7 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "title" => "test"
    "link" => "test"
    "description" => "<p>test</p>"
    "image" => "1493112569-break-into-your-heart.jpg"
    "created_at" => "2017-04-25 09:25:21"
    "updated_at" => "2017-04-25 09:29:29"
  ]
  #original: array:7 [▶]
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #events: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
}
```

Specifically, `item` in the response is being returned as follows:

```
"item": {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "test",
    "link": "test",
    "description": "<p>test</p>",
    "image": "1493112569-break-into-your-heart.jpg",
    "created_at": "2017-04-25 09:25:21",
    "updated_at": "2017-04-25 09:29:29"
},
```

Now what's occurring is that the title is being successfully displayed on the page, but I'm also getting an error which is the following:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render function: 
TypeError: _vm.project.item is undefined
```

Which is also causing the rest of my scripts to fail. Any idea as to why it's clearly displaying the information in the project object but still spitting out the error?

I can also see the **project** object with the relevant loaded attributes in Vue DevTools on page load/transition.

Comment: Each array has index so rather than storing items to array try with object.But that depends on your need, other option would be specific index targeting or iterating over array.

Comment: Tried with object, same issue. What's weird is that the data is being correctly assigned and I can display information in `project`.

Comment: Okay, does this maybe work - `<h1 v-if="project" v-text="project.item.title"></h1>` ?

Comment: Instead of showing the code that returns the datum, could you show the actual, serialized content returned from the server?  In your data function `project` is an array, but your `v-text` binding doesn't access an element of the array.

Comment: Done. I have tried to explicitly declare a nested object `item` in `project` to no avail. What I've noticed though is the following. If I just return `$project` and then try to display `project.title`, that works perfectly. This issue arose only when I tried to nest `$project` in a named key called `item` in the response and then tried to display `project.item.title`. That does display the project's title on the page, but still generates the error.

Comment: @Frisbetarian you should be getting the error in either cases. As you try to access project.item.title or project.title before project actually has any of these properties. You can declare the structure inside your data with undefined values or you can use v-if to avoid these errors.